# How to know when SQL query has finished

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, sql-update

I´m trying to create a logic to update massively the column "Prices" from table "Products".

This logic is made, but in my C# code I send the command to the MS Access DB, and immediately I want to show the new results.

The problem is that the update query takes a few seconds to finish, and my C# instantaneously asks for the Select from Products, showing no changes.

The main question is how I can know when the update has finished to show the new results in the grid.

Here my code:

```
private void btnAceptar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string operator;
        int code = Convert.ToInt32(cmbcode .SelectedValue);
        int material = Convert.ToInt32(cmbMaterial.SelectedValue);
        int productType= Convert.ToInt32(cmbproductType.SelectedValue);

        if (cmboperating.SelectedIndex == 0){ operator= "+"; }
        else if (cmboperating.SelectedIndex == 1) { operator= "-"; }
        else if (cmboperating.SelectedIndex == 2) { operator= "*"; }
        else { operator= "/"; }

        if(txtValoroperating.Text != "") { txtValoroperating.Text = (txtValoroperating.Text).Replace(",", "."); }
        string operating = txtValoroperating.Text;
        if(rdPrecioDeLista.Checked == true & cbTodasPiezas.Checked == true)
        {
            //Here is my problem
            oProductsDAL.modifyPricesMassively(operating, operator);
            txtValoroperating.Text = null;
            fillGridProducts();
        }
    }
```

And oProductsDAL.modifyPricesMassively(operating, operator) does this:

```
public bool modifyPricesMassively(operating, operator)
        {
            if (operating!= "" & operator!= "")
            {
                return conexion.executeMethod("UPDATE Piezas SET Precio = Precio " +operator+" " +operating);
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

conexion.executeMethod does this:

```
public bool conexion.executeMethod(string strComando)
        {
            try
            {
                OleDbCommand Comando = new OleDbCommand();
                Comando.CommandText = strComando;
                Comando.Connection = this.establecerConexion();
                Conexion.Open();
                Comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Conexion.Close();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No se pudo establecer conexion con la base de datos" +ex);
                return false;
            }
        }
```

I wish to show a progress bar or a gif loading icon.

Comment: Hello! Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), knowing how to ask is the key to get an answer

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: how are you sending the command to MS Access? If you are running the code synchronously then you would know when it is finished, but since you don't I assume you aren't, so how exactly are you sending the command to Access to run the update?

Comment: Hello guys, i have updated the post. Sorry if bad transated, I wrote my code in spanish, first time programing